# notice trying to access array offset on value of type null wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, notice, php-7.4

i must update my website to the last version of php 7.4 after that i find this notice in some plugins

**> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

> C:\projets\htdocs\mapsport\wp-content\plugins\ekit-megamenu\library\scss\scss.inc.php
> on line 1753**

```
protected function sortArgs($prototype, $args) {
    $keyArgs = array();
    $posArgs = array();

    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        list($key, $value) = $arg;
        $key = $key[1]; // line 1753
        if (empty($key)) {
            $posArgs[] = $value;
        } else {
            $keyArgs[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($prototype)) return $posArgs;

    $finalArgs = array();
    foreach ($prototype as $i => $names) {
        if (isset($posArgs[$i])) {
            $finalArgs[] = $posArgs[$i];
            continue;
        }

        $set = false;
        foreach ((array)$names as $name) {
            if (isset($keyArgs[$name])) {
                $finalArgs[] = $keyArgs[$name];
                $set = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$set) {
            $finalArgs[] = null;
        }
    }

    return $finalArgs;
}
```

how can i change the code without change my php version ?

the result after add var_dump($args); before the foreach Suggested by @Ro Achterberg

> array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> array(2) { [0]=>
> string(3) "var" [1]=> string(23) "ekit-menu-simple__white" } [2]=>
> bool(false) } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> array(3) { [0]=>
> string(6) "number" [1]=> string(3) "6.5" [2]=> string(1) "%" } [2]=>
> bool(false) } }

Comment: To debug this it will help to know the actual value of `$args`. While some of the syntax in that code is outdated, it should still work in 7.4. The problem likely exists somewhere in or before the function that calls `sortArgs()`. Please do a `var_dump($args);` before the `foreach` and update your answer to show us its result.

Comment: Ro achterberg  u update the question after debug the error

Comment: It looks like you're not passing the array structure to `sortArgs()` it expects. Looking at the [plugin compatibility table](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementskit-lite/advanced/), assuming I found the one you're using, it is tested up to PHP 5.5.3. I would suggest you consult their support forum for help first, as this seems to be a proprietary issue.

Answer (score 1):

On line `1752` the value of `$key` is `NULL`. It doesn't get any value. So can you please try `$key = isset( $key[1] ) ? $key[1] : '';`?